# Find the model for an unknown (non-Häger) wall thermostat?

Tags: heating, thermostat

I recently bought a house, after years in a flat. Many things are novel to me, especially the heating system. The digital [thermostat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermostat) is of an unknown  brand, the former owner could not tell me (I suspect he did not use it), and I am looking for a user manual. It looked like a Häger screen to me, so I sent them, and they answered it was not.

Do these pictures ring a bell to someone who could help me find the model? Top-left: view without the slidable panel to uncover the buttons; Top-right: slidable panel turned +90° (probably a sticker made for the French); Bottom-right: inside view; Bottom-left: zoom on the printed circuit.

[image: Home Thermostat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is a "Thermostat programmable hebdomadaire castorama", as shown in the below image (found on the Internet). A closely-related manual (not the exact model, but the same functionalities) used to be available under address `http://www.castorama.fr/media_aux/810203_a1.pdf`, but not anymore. [My own copy is here](http://www.laurent-duval.eu/_Share/Temp/Castorama-Thermostat-810203_a1.pdf).

[image: Thermostat programmable hebdomadaire castorama]

Comment: Personal copy http://www.laurent-duval.eu/_Share/Temp/Castorama-Thermostat-810203_a1.pdf